# How to split long lines in Xml files without spaces?

Tags: xml

```
<file>/up/mp/testconst/myproject/project1/source/inc/file.c<file>
```

Trying to Split the above line as given below.

```
 <file>/up/mp/testconst/mypro
ject/project1/source/inc/file.c<file>
```

But this adds a space in the path as shown:

```
<file>/up/mp/testconst/myproj ect/project1/source/inc/file.c<file>
```

Comment: How are you splitting the line?

Comment: @TA — Presumably by pressing the Enter key in a text editor.

Comment: Yes, by an enter

Comment: Your text editor may have a feature to wrap lines visually without changing the content of the file.  Also, you should be aware of when whitespace matters in an XML file.  See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51786377/290085) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace is (largely) all equal in XML. You can't add it in the middle of a word purely for formatting the source code.

The closest you could come would be to define your XML application so that it supported elements which could be joined together.

```
<file>
    <foo>/up/mp/testconst/mypro</foo>
    <foo>ject/project1/source/inc/file.c</foo>
</file>
```

All the software processing your XML would have to be written to get the value by merging the text nodes inside the `foo` elements while ignoring content outside of them.

I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's answer is correct (+1).  Please also be aware of the following:

1. Whitespace ***between*** elements and attributes is generally ***insignificant*** and can be added or expanded for pretty printing.
2. Whitespace ***within*** element and attribute ***values*** is generally ***significant*** and should not be changed or added merely for formatting.
3. Some editors will have settings to enable line wrapping.  This feature is for ease of viewing only and thus may be of help to you without actually changing the contents of the file.